# How do I get SQL Server Management Studio to save CSV in the correct format?

Tags: sql, csv, replace, ssms, quotes

If I don't add anything and just "Save Results As..." csv then everything is quoted and separated correctly except for the first and last column.

I have a later version of SQL Server Management Studio that does not include the option "`Quote strings containing list separators when saving .csv results`". I have used both REPLACE and QUOTENAME to try and get it in the right format.

For instance, it should look like `"00301", "1020", "Description", "Email" but without any changes I get 00301, "1020", "Description", Email.`

When I use QUOTENAME to add quotes to the first and last columns, it shows the correct format in the Results window but when I save as csv, it now adds extra quotes to those columns. Now I get `"""00301""", "1020", "Description", """Email"""`

When I use REPLACE it concatenates it into one column and still does not quote correctly.

Comment: SSMS knows the datatypes of the columns and doesn't quote int columns.

Comment: CSV data only requires quotes around column data under certain circumstances (the primary one being that the column data contains a comma, which without quotes would be considered a column separator - surrounding the value in quotes escapes the embedded separator). Your first example output seems to be perfectly fine - the missing quotes aren't required. Are you having a specific issue with that CSV file, or are you just upset because you think there should be quotes around every value?

Comment: In order to upload it into the program I need, I need every value to be quoted. You say it doesn't quote int columns, but the last column I have is not int.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution through add-in that I develop:
SSMSBoost can export ResultsGrid in several ways, the one, that you need is called "ResultsGrid scripter". It uses customizeable templates to export data to files.
You can use one of present templates to create your own (which is pretty easy).

Video about data export, where scripter is referenced: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waDCukeXeLU

Description of the feature: https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-results-grid-script-results